# How to align two primefaces-elements correctly?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I use a menubar from primefaces

```
<p:toolbar style="margin:20px 0px">
     <f:facet name="left">
        <p:outputLabel value="#{loginBean.fullname}" />
     </f:facet>

     <f:facet name="right">
        <p:inputText style="margin-right:10px" placeholder="Search" disabled="true"/>
        <p:themeSwitcher effectSpeed="normal" effect="fade" style="width:165px; margin-right:10px;" id="defaultSwitcher" value="#{themeSwitcherBean.theme}">
           <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choose Theme" itemValue="" />
           <f:selectItems value="#{themeSwitcherBean.themes}" />
           <p:ajax global="false" listener="#{themeSwitcherBean.saveTheme}" />
        </p:themeSwitcher>
        <p:commandButton action="#{loginBean.logout}" title="Log Out" style="width:36px; height:20px" icon="ui-icon-power" value="" ajax="false"></p:commandButton>
     </f:facet>
</p:toolbar>
```

which renders to the right side

[image]

It disturb my eye that the alignment fro mthe search-box and the drop-down-box are not at the same height.

You know how i can align them correctly?

Answer (score -1):

You need to fix the drop-down-box appearance using with CSS. Try to add "margin-top" or "padding-top" property to the p:themeSwitcher style arrtibute.

Comment: does anyone knows the better solution?